# Doxygen define custom annotation for use with Unity "Tooltip" attribute

Tags: unity-game-engine, plugins, configuration, doxygen

I am using [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org) (version 1.8.11) to document a [Unity](https://unity3d.com/) (version 2017.3.0f3) project and it is working great so far. However here is an example of a small inefficiency I am looking to resolve:

Requirements:

1. I want Unity to display a tooltip when I hover over a public field with some info on what the field does [as seen in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKInH.png)

   - `[Tooltip("The room's center transform")]`
2. I want Doxygen to document the field and display the same info in the docs [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUXII.png)

   - `/// <value> The room's center transform</value>`

To accomplish this I currently need to enter the same information twice in my source code ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zIDr.png))

How can I configure Doxygen to read all `[Tooltip("...")]` sections instead of all `/// <value>...</value>` sections?

If this is not possible using built-in functionality, how can I get started with writing a Doxygen plugin or extension to configure Doxygen's parser to achieve this?

EDIT: Doxygen version 1.8.11, Unity version 2017.3.0f3

Comment: Please specify the doxygen version your are using. Please include the images in the post as they might not be persistent.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, added versions via edit.
Unfortunately I am unable to embed images as I am under 10 reputation.

Comment: Please try version 1.8.14 (current version), when persistent please post some example code to reproduce the problem, currently I'm thinking about the ALIASES configuration in the Doxyfile as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Linux you can use the 'sed' command which uses regular expressions for substitutions using INPUT_FILTER.

```
"sed -r 's/\[Tooltip[(]+\"([a-zA-z[:space:]_.!?\\\-\*\/|+=]+).*/\/\/\/ \<summary\>\1\<\/summary\>/'"
```

This will replace something like '[Tooltip("Example!")]' with '/// <summary>Example!</summary>' using regex.

Edit: if you're on windows you can use something like Cygwin and point directly to the command for example:

```
"C:/cygwin64/bin/sed.exe -r 's/\[Tooltip[(]+\"([a-zA-z[:space:]_.!?\\\-\*\/|+=]+).*/\/\/\/ \<summary\>\1\<\/summary\>/'"
```

Comment: You wrote: " This will modify the original source files so I suggest you use git or somethng to revert the files back to their original source after documentation generation. (-i does not seem to work)". Doxygen does not modify the original sources when using and `INPUT_FILTER` setting in doxygen. Which version of doxygen did you use?

Comment: @albert I just tested and you're correct it doesn't modify anything. When I did a quick test before I answered I had done a test with and without the in-place argument (-i) so of course sed modified it when I used -i. Thanks for pointing that out, I will correct my answer.